# Java regex String parse, trying to figure out a pattern

Tags: java, regex

```
File file = new File("file-type-string-i-want-2000-01-01-01-01-01.conf.gz");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.compile("\\-(.*)\\-\\d{4}")).matcher(fileName);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (matcher.find()) {
                sb.append(matcher.group());
            }
            stringList = Arrays.asList(sb.toString().split("-"));
            if (stringList.size() >= 2) {
                nameFragment = stringList.get(stringList.size() - 2);
            }
```

Desired result is to extract

```
string-iwant
```

from strings that look like this

```
file-type-string-iwant-2000-01-01-01-01-01.conf.gz
```

Unfortunatly, the format for "string-iwant" is a non-fixed length of alpha-numeric characters that will include only ONE hyphen BUT never start with a hyphen. The date formatting is consistent, the year is always after the string, so my current approach is to match on the -year, but I'm having difficulty excluding the stuff at the beginning.

Thanks for any thoughts or ideas

Edit: updated strings

Comment: What about the `file-type` part, can that contain hyphen?  If yes, what else makes it different from `string-i-want`?

Comment: file-type may contain a hyphen or may not

Comment: You cannot exclude the part at the beginning because you did not define what it is with enough clarity. From your current description, an extra assumption is needed to tell `"type-string-i-want"` from `"string-i-want"` or even from `"i-want"` or `"want"`.

Comment: @Hoofamon - in that case you need to find another quality that differentiates the two parts (e.g. `string-i-want` always contains a specific amount of hyphens), otherwise there is no way to tell the difference with a regexp

Comment: @Hoofamon If `file-type` may or may not contain a hyphen, how do you tell apart `"string-i-want"` and `"type-string-i-want"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the regex you need:

`\\-([^-]+\\-[^-]+)\\-\\d{4}\\-`

Basically it means:

- `-` starts with minus
- `([^-]+\\-[^-]+)` contains 1 or more non-minus symbols, then a minus, then 1 or more non-minus symbols. This part is captured.
- `-\d{4}` a minus sign and 4 digits

However, that will only work if `stuff-you-need` has only **one** hyphen (or a constant amount of hyphens, which will need correction in regex). Otherwise, there is no way to know if given the string `file-type-string-i-want` the word `type` belongs to a sting you want or not.

**Added:**

In case the `file-type` always contains exactly one hyphen, you can capture the required part this way:

`[^-]+\\-[^-]+\\-(.*)\\-\\d{4}\\-`

Explanation:

- `[^-]+\-[^-]+\\-` some amount of non-hyphen characters, then a hyphen, then more non-hyphens. This will skip the `file-type` string with the following hyphen.
- `\-\d{4}\-` a hyphen, 4 digits followed by another hyphen
- `(.*)` everything in between of previous 2 statements is captured as being the string you need to select

Comment: I don't get the impression that the capture should contain exactly one hyphen . . . just that hyphen is a valid character for that portion of the string.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing in this part: "Unfortunatly, the format for "string-i-want" is a non-fixed length of alpha-numeric characters that will __include a hyphen__ BUT never start with a hyphen.", is it ONE hyphen, or is it ANY amount of hyphens.

Comment: sorry, it is indeed only 1 hyphen so I should have said string-iwant

Comment: @Hoofamon then the first part (before "__Added:__") will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If it were PHP I would use something like the following to capture that string.

```
/^(\w+\-){2}(?<string>.+?)\-\d{4}(\-\d{2}){5}(\.\w+){2}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex that I would use for this purpose is this with a positive lookahead:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^-]+-[^-]+(?=-\\d{4})");
```

Which simply means match the text containing **exactly one hyphen** followed by **one hyphen and a 4 digit year**.

Then you can simply grab the `matcher.group(0)` as your matched text which will be `string-iwant` in this case.